# Jquery sticky menu not being caught by footer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Can anyone help me pinpoint the issue with my script please?

```
$(function () {
var top = $('#sidebar').offset().top - parseFloat($('#sidebar').css('marginTop').replace(/auto/, 0));
var footTop = $('#footer').offset().top - parseFloat($('#footer').css('marginTop').replace(/auto/, 0));
var maxY = footTop - $('#sidebar').outerHeight();
$(window).scroll(function (evt) {
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (y > 100) {
        if (y < maxY) {
            $('#sidebar').addClass('stickyside').removeAttr('style');
        } else {
            $('#sidebar').removeClass('stickyside').css({
                position: 'absolute',
                top: (maxY - top) + 'px'
            });
        }
    } else {
        $('#sidebar').removeClass('stickyside');
    }
});
});
```

Live site here - https://tregothnan.co.uk/tea-herbal-infusions/

Sticky sidenav is spilling over the footer div and no matter what I try I can't get it to work. It works fine in my jsfiddle prototype.

Comment: Could you try reproducing the issue in JSFiddle? Or at least link to the working prototype.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/katch/cmp20k3w/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you are forgetting the `margin-top` of your sidebar in your calculation:

```
var maxY = footTop - $('#sidebar').outerHeight() - 68;
```

In your Prototype JSFiddle the sidebar just happened to have no `margin-top`.

---

On a sidenote: you may want to cache your selectors to improve performance. If you use the same selector more than once, for example `$("#sidebar")`, put it in a variable:
`var sidebar = $("#sidebar");`.

Comment: Changes made to live and still overflowing.

Comment: @DavidH I think your changes weren't applied correctly. It works when I test it on your live site.

Comment: Live site still spilling on Chrome - but the sticky applies earlier - about 90% through the twitter feed.

Comment: @DavidH Alright, the problem here is that your `margin-top` changes while you are scrolling. If you are on the top of the site, you have `margin-top: 18px;`, but when you scroll down, the `margin-top` becomes `68px`. So when you first calculate `maxY` it uses the `18px` value instead of the `68px` which you need at the end. You'll need to recalculate your `maxY` inside the scroll function. I've edited my answer.

Comment: getting closer but still some funny rendering and artefacts going on - spilling still there.

Comment: @DavidH Hmpf... Now the problem is that every time the `stickyside` class is removed, the margin changes again, and then the `maxY` gets recalculated by the wrong margin, resulting it into adding the `stickyside` class again which changes the margin again... etc. The easiest solution would be to hardcode your `maxY` to use `68px`. Is this is a viable solution for you?

Comment: yeah that would be fine - how best to implement (sorry not really a developer but learning)

Comment: @DavidH Edited my answer. Incase your `.stickyside` margin ever changes, you'll need to edit the value in your javascript to fit this. Whenever you copy a function or script, do try to understand what exactly happens and how the code works. If you're having trouble with this, feel free to ask for explanations or quick help in one of the [SO Chatrooms](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29074/html-css-webdesign), we'll be glad to help you learn.

Comment: I don't have the rep to join you guys in chat.  Changes made and it now lands in the correct place but artefacts on the scroll.  Really appreciating the assistance.  Had to use a value of 85 to land the #sidebar in the right place.

Comment: @DavidH Use `68`, not `85`. Otherwhise it will still overflow for a bit. If you want to add a margin between the footer and the sidebar then you need to add `-20` to your `footTop`. As for your rep, you just need 20 rep to join a chat, so try posting some answers to other people's questions.

Comment: @DavidH On a sidenote you should have enough rep for the Chatrooms now ;D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71579/discussion-between-david-h-and-dark-ashelin).

Answer (score 1):

Ok - many thanks @dark-ashelin

ended up with this - bit of a hack but it works.

```
$(function () {
var sidebar = $("#sidebar");
var top = $('#sidebar').offset().top - parseFloat($('#sidebar').css('marginTop').replace(/auto/, 0));
var footTop = $('#footer').offset().top - parseFloat($('#footer').css('marginTop').replace(/auto/, 0))-60;
var maxY = footTop - $('#sidebar').outerHeight() - 85;
$(window).scroll(function (evt) {
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();

    if (y > 100) {
        if (y < maxY) {
            $('#sidebar').addClass('stickyside').removeAttr('style');
        } else {
            $('#sidebar').removeClass('stickyside').css({
                position: 'absolute',
                top: (maxY + 50) + 'px'
            });
        }
    } else {
        $('#sidebar').removeClass('stickyside');
    }
});
});
```

Comment: If DarkAshelin's answer has solved your issue you should mark it as correct.